# How to handle save button click event on my list form in SPD?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to call my custom function after that call the save button click function on my list form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this by leveraging the PreSaveAction function.

You'd introduce javascript like such at a base level:

```
function PreSaveAction(){
  //do my stuff
  return true;
}
```

If you are trying to do some sort of validation, you'd do it like this:

```
function PreSaveAction(){
  if(1 !== 0){
   return false;
  }
 else{
  return true;
 }      
}
```

The point being you need to return true to continue the save process or return false to halt the save process.

https://spandps.com/2011/01/25/useful-javascript-function-presaveaction-sp2010-sharepoint-ps2010-projectserver-in/

Comment: Hey its work. For Cancel button click  PreCancelAction() ?

Comment: There is no override function for cancel buttons like presaveaction, you'd have to bind your own click function to the cancel button if you had custom logic you needed to execute on cancel.